# npm: "Cannot find module internal/errors"

Tags: node.js, npm

On a MacBook with the latest version of NodeJS, I am trying to update npm:

```
npm install npm@latest
```

The error message is:

```
npm ERR: code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR: Cannot find module 'internal/errors'
npm ERR: A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR:     /Users/alexander/.npm/_logs/2017_09_15_12_35_47_079Z-debug.log
```

and the referenced log file reads

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'npm@latest' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.5.0
4 verbose npm-session 5db7f116200ca64c
5 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'internal/errors'
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
5 verbose stack     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:36:16
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
5 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:3:27)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
6 verbose cwd /Users/alexander/Documents/Source/Repos
7 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
8 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "npm@latest"
9 verbose node v8.5.0
10 verbose npm  v5.3.0
11 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
12 error Cannot find module 'internal/errors'
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The same worked ok on the windows machine.

What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to reinstall npm from the package in node v6.11.3LTS, and then

try to update to the latest npm v5.4.2

`npm install npm@latest -g`

and then update to the latest node v8.3.0

`npm install node@latest -g`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, the above answer did not work.

I had old versions in node_modules.

I simply deleted everything in node_modules and then ran:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: I cant run npm with nothing it throws an error  C:\Users\pirat>npm
module.js:529
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/errors'

Comment: @Xvegas It's because you are running a newer version of Node than NPM was installed with. Revert to your previous version, then upgrade NPM, and then upgrade to a new Node version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I solve it:

1. uninstall node and npm, do as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/4222801).
2. then install node

   ```
   brew install node
   ```

   and npm will also be installed.