# Can't install using npm install -g react-native-cli

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, react-native-cli

Trying to install `react-native-cli` with

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

results in this error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/kamleshtilwani/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/bin/node" "/Users/kamleshtilwani/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v8.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.4.1
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/errors'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/kamleshtilwani/npm-debug.log
```

[image: NPM install error]

Answer (score 0):

A quick test on my Mac suggests that updating `npm` will do the trick for you.

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240497/npm-cannot-find-module-internal-errors) (also on Mac) also seems to suggest that bumping npm version (to 5.4.2 in this case) will get rid of this error.

I was able to install `react-native-cli` on my Mac using npm 5.0.0.  I downgraded to npm 3.4.1, tried to install again, and got an error similar to yours, although mine was barking about `internal/fs` instead of `internal/errors`.

Good luck!